# GROQ query for getStaticPaths with nested dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I have a nested folder structure in my NextJS project. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JWdH.png)

I am using Sanity as my CMS. getStaticPaths inside my index.js file works correctly:

```
 export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const routes = await getClient()
    .fetch(`*[_type == 'collection'][].slug.current`)

  return {
    paths: routes.map((slug) => ({ params: { collection_slug: slug } })),
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

but I am lost when it comes to creating a GROQ query that can correctly load my paths in product/[product_slug].js. Product and Collections types are related by a reference.

I keep getting this error:

Error: A required parameter (collection_slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /collections/[collection_slug]/product/[product_slug]

How would I correctly format my query/params deeper in my nested route?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should query this in sanity vison:

`*[_type== 'collection' && defined(slug.current)]`

any collection document that has the attribute `slug.current` this
will give you all the slugs in collection documents which
`getStaticPaths` will use to generate paths

```js
 export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const routes = await getClient()
    .fetch(`*[_type == 'collection' && defined(slug.current)][].slug.current`)

  return {
    paths: routes.map((slug) => ({ params: { collection_slug: slug } })),
    fallback: true
  }
}
```